# www domain redirects to none www domain using cloudflare

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare and Digitalocean. I have setup my name servers and in Cloudflare I have these settings:

```
A: mydomain.com -> 1.2.3.4.5 

CNAME: www -> mydomain.com
```

But when I visit my site by www.example.com I get redirected to:

https://example.com

So how can I keep the www part in my domain?

Comment: share your apache host entry and .htaccess content as this is the cause behind this

Comment: @sandeepgoel I am using nginx, what conf file should I share?

Comment: kindly share /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com and your htaccess also

Answer (score 2):

The only way to insert HTTP redirects in Cloudflare is currently via Page Rules. If you don't have a redirect set in your Page Rules than this redirect must be on your Origin server.

As this is the case you will need to alter this in your application. For example, on WordPress you can do this in the admin dashboard (Settings > General, then changing the URLs there to include WWW).

[image: WordPress URL options]

Comment: I tried setup a page rule but I got an error saying too many redirects :/

Answer (score 1):

You should go to page rules as below

[image]

There are two kind of redirect

```
  Permanet redirect 301
  Temporary redirect 302
```

Example

As you can see in below Picture all request to **www.xxx.info**
will redirect to **xxx.com**

here * means all Paramter will accepted by cloudflare and put in place of $1 in redirect URL

[image]